# Get all styles in office 365 Word document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365

I just start to familiar with office 365 word add-in development. I am trying to get all existing styles in a word document using word JavaScript API. But I couldn't find any method to do it. Can someone show me how to do that using word JavaScript API?

Comment: I don't see anything about styles in the [Word js API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview), but there is a [Working with styles](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md#working-with-styles) section that mentions the `/word/styles.xml` file, so you can probably use it to get the styles info

Comment: Thanks @Slai. Yes. There is no mention about styles in Word js API. But I believe there should be a way to manipulate styles in a Word document. I also studied about the ways add styles in office open xml. Can anyone tell me aren't Microsoft support this feature yet?

Comment: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/contentcontrol?product=word

Comment: @Slai, Thanks again. Yeah I saw this. But its all about style property in the API. But not about styles.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible today with as strongly type object of the API. you can use existing styles (built in or added manually), but you cannot create or list insertion point, you can get the styles that are included in the document as part of the delivered XML. check out the [sample here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/body.md#getooxml) on how to get the OOXML of a selection. Every returned OOXML must return the style package that includes that information. Looks like this: (look for the style package

```html
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/styles.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml">
<pkg:xmlData>
  <w:styles xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se">
    <w:docDefaults>
      <w:rPrDefault>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cstheme="minorBidi"/>
          <w:sz w:val="22"/>
          <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
          <w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="en-US" w:bidi="ar-SA"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:rPrDefault>
      <w:pPrDefault>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:spacing w:after="160" w:line="259" w:lineRule="auto"/>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:pPrDefault>
    </w:docDefaults>
    <w:latentStyles w:defLockedState="0" w:defUIPriority="99" w:defSemiHidden="0" w:defUnhideWhenUsed="0" w:defQFormat="0" w:count="373">
      <w:lsdException w:name="Normal" w:uiPriority="0" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 1" w:uiPriority="9" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 2" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="9" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 3" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="9" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 4" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="9" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 5" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="9" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 6" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="9" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 7" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="9" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 8" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="9" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="heading 9" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="9" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 1" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 2" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 3" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 4" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 5" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 6" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 7" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 8" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index 9" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 1" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 2" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 3" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 4" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 5" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 6" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 7" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 8" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toc 9" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="39" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="Normal Indent" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="footnote text" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="annotation text" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="header" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="footer" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="index heading" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="caption" w:semiHidden="1" w:uiPriority="35" w:unhideWhenUsed="1" w:qFormat="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="table of figures" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="envelope address" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="envelope return" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="footnote reference" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="annotation reference" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="line number" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="page number" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="endnote reference" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="endnote text" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="table of authorities" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="macro" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="toa heading" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Bullet" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Number" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List 2" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List 3" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List 4" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List 5" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Bullet 2" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Bullet 3" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Bullet 4" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Bullet 5" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Number 2" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Number 3" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Number 4" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="List Number 5" w:semiHidden="1" w:unhideWhenUsed="1"/>
      <w:lsdException w:name="Title" w:uiPriority="10" w:qFormat="1"/>
```

please submit a request (or vote for an existing one) for the styles strongly typed object in user voice.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/163566-add-in-word

would be great to include your scenario.

thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is really important. Could you please tell me is there a way to get the in styles in word?

Comment: Hello! as i am suggesting in my answer, you will need to get the OOXML and then get the styles from there.

Comment: Thanks again, Actually I tested this with 4 short paragraphs. Then I got 12-14 long OOXML. So seems like size of the ooxml is extremely large comparing with the document. Is there a way to simplify this ooxml document for processing purposes?

Comment: not when you are reading it from the document. you are interested only on the style package though, so a simple Xpath should take you there quite fast.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to install  XPath in office 365 project?

Comment: hello! you dont need to install anything, Xpath is just a technology used to query an XML document. There are many JS libraries you can use for this  here is one you can explore https://github.com/ilinsky/xpath.js . Here is more info about Xpath https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath