# List/Enumerate all Word Styles (custom & predefined) with Office.JS API

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Im developing a Word Addin with Javascript Office API and have the following requirements:

- List all custom/user-defined Word Styles in a document and get the type (e.g. is it a table style or a paragraph/character style, etc.)
- List the built in word styles with a localized name and get also the type

The only thing i found was the builtin Word.Style Enum for predefined Styles, and i couldnt find a way to get the localized name.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I think that currently, the best option is to get the document as Ooxml and get the list of styles from there.

**Short version:**
You can use `getSelectedDataAsync()` with coercion type `Ooxml` to retrieve the document and then descend down to `//pkg:part[@pkg:name="/word/styles.xml"]//w:styles` which will contain a `w:style` for every style known to the document.

**Longer version:**
Try sth. along the lines of this (I use jQuery here to keep things short):

```js
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(
  Office.CoercionType.Ooxml,
  ( result ) => {
    let xml = $.parseXML(result.value);
    let styles = $(xml).find("w\\:styles");
    styles.children().each( ( index, style ) => {
      console.log(style);
    });
  }
);
```

`getSelectedDataAsync()` here returns a complete description of the document in the form of a Flat OPC file. Then, retrieve all descendants `w:style`.
These elements look sth. like this:

```xml
<w:style
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    w:type="paragraph"
    w:default="1"
    w:styleId="Standard">
  <w:name w:val="Normal"/>
  <w:qFormat/>
  <w:rsid w:val="00BF72CE"/>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Segoe UI Historic" w:hAnsi="Segoe UI Historic" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
    <w:sz w:val="22"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
  </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

You’d be interested in the attributes `w:style/@w:styleId` (which is the internal ID of this style if it is a predefined style) and `w:style/w:name/@w:val` (which is the (localized) name of the style).

(I got the basic idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39355093/1652861)

Comment: Hey dariok, thanks for the answer! yesterday i also implemented this approach. and i think it works well for user defined styles and builtin styles used in the document.